# Laravel : String type always returning 2147483647

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

When i am retrieving data via api i am getting 2147483647 although i have created that column in string column type. In table it is successfully storing 989547****.

**Migration:**

```
$table->string('source_number',10)->unique();
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getSourceNumberSmsTemplate(Request $request){
    $detail=$request->all();

    if(empty($detail['source_number']) || !array_key_exists('source_number',$detail)){
        return Response::json([
        'message' => "Missing Parameters. Please recheck submitted data"], 422);
    }

    $template= smstemplate::find($detail['source_number']);
    return Response::json([
        $detail['source_number']=>$template], 200);
    }
```

**Api result:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "source_number": 2147483647,
 }
```

Comment: kindly post this complete function $template= smstemplate::find($detail['source_number']);
    return Response::json([
        $detail['source_number']=>$template], 200);

Comment: Please show the complete code. Your API result, doesn't match with what you are sending from your controller. The method returns an array with the source_number as key and the template as value, where your API result is an object, with an id, user_id and a source_number.

Comment: try this
smstemplate::where('source_number' ,$detail['source_number']);

Comment: Still getting same result.

Comment: try this:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::table('sms_templates')->where('source_number', '=' , $request->source_number)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try query builder:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$template = DB::table('sms_templates')
->where('source_number', '=' , $request->source_number)
->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Casting it to bigint or string in your Model, by default it is an integer'

//like below

```
protected $keyType = 'bigint';
```